# MSSQL select single row with all references counted

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am attempting to do something using MSSQL that I believe is possible (easily) but I do not know how to vocalize the correct search string. I have the situation below.

```
Table A
UID  | Value....
1    | a
2    | b
3    | c


Table B
PartTypes_uid_fk   | Value....
1           | a
1           | b
1           | c
1           | d
1           | e
3           | 67
3           | 1354
```

I am attempting to get the following result, query Table A for all results {TableA.*} and on the same row result show the number of table b references {count TableB.tableA_fk}
What I have so far is the following.

`SELECT DISTINCT t1.uid, CONVERT(varchar(MAX), t1.Name) AS Name, CONVERT(varchar(MAX), t1.Description) AS Description, 
Count(t2.Items_uid_fk) OVER (Partition By t2.PartTypes_uid_fk) as Count 
FROM [Table1] as t1 left outer join Table2 as t2 on t2.PartTypes_uid_fk=t1.uid;`

This works for all of Table A records with an associated record in Table B but if there are 0 entries in Table B it won't work. The conversion of the varchars was required due to the fact they are ntext format and it was distinct.

Thank you for all your help in advance.
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running into problems with the `GROUP BY on N/TEXT` columns, and to run faster, you would want to pre-aggregate the B table and LEFT JOIN that against A.

```
select t1.*, ISNULL(t2.c, 0) AS CountOfB
from table1 t1
left join
(
    select parttypes_uid_fk, count(*) c
    from table2
    group by parttypes_uid_fk
) t2 on t2.PartTypes_uid_fk=t1.uid
```

Comment: +1. I didn't read the ntext.  This is going to be your most efficient means.  SQL will be smart about optimizing this and not do a table scan when matching the subquery to the main query.  So I think this is the solution that should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than that:

```
SELECT t1.uid, t1.Name, COUNT(*)
FROM [Table1] t1
LEFT JOIN [Table2] t2 ON t2.PartTypes_uid_fk = t1.uid
GROUP BY t1.uid, t1.Name
```

Comment: Missed description, but add it to the select list and group by list and it's the same.

Comment: Sorry about the edit, but this has the same problem. Any count of 0 is not returned as a row.
PS thanks for the help

Comment: @spraus I added my vote for RichardTheKiwi's solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13296467/1795053  I think it's the best solution offered so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
SELECT t1.uid, 
CONVERT(varchar(MAX), t1.Name) AS Name, 
CONVERT(varchar(MAX), t1.Description) AS Description, 
Count(t2.Items_uid_fk) CountItems 
FROM [Table1] as t1 left outer join Table2 as t2 on t1.uid = t2.PartTypes_uid_fk
GROUP BY uid, t1.name, t1.Description;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and that will work if not for the issues displaying the results with 0 count.